# Paypal transaction not displayed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, transactions, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have integrated Paypal sandbox , live

Transaction shows like success, but i cant able to see the transaction list on Developer dashboard.
code:

```
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new
@pay = @api.build_pay({
   :actionType => "PAY",
   :cancelUrl => "http://localhost:3000/adaptive_payments/pay",
   :currencyCode => "USD",
   :feesPayer => "SENDER",
  :ipnNotificationUrl => "http://localhost:3000/adaptive_payments/ipn_notify",
   :receiverList => {
     :receiver => [{
       :amount => 1.0,
       :email => "xxxxxx@gmail.com" }] },
       :returnUrl => "http://localhost:3000/adaptive_payments/pay"
 })
  @response = @api.pay(@pay)
   key = @response.payKey
```

Response:

```
Response.body={
  "responseEnvelope": {
  "timestamp": "2015-09-28T03:48:23.428-07:00",
  "ack": "Success",
  "correlationId": "xxxxx",
  "build": "17820627"
},
"payKey": "xxxx",
"paymentExecStatus": "CREATED"
}
```

yml file:

```
production:
  mode: live
  app_id: xxxxx
  username: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx
  signature: xxxxxxxx
  client_id: xxxxxxxx
  client_secret: xxxxxxxxx
```

PayKey is generated, but i need to send credit to user PayPal from backend through API, without redirecting to webpage
Is there any other way, to pay instantly without webpage intraction.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you won't see the transactionID in either of the environments because no transaction was made yet.

By running the `build_pay` method you only built the Pay object and redirected him to PayPal payment page.

To receive the payment transactionID after the client paid you will need to run the `payment_details` method with the relevant PAY-KEY (AP-...) you saved before redirecting the client to the payment page, here is an example:

```
def self.get_payment_details(key_str)
  api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new
  pp_request = api.build_payment_details
  pp_request.pay_key = key_str
  api.payment_details(pp_request)
end

get_payment_details(PAY_KEY_GOES_HERE)
```

Update:

The paymentExecStatus shows it's in Created state which means there was no payment made yet. 
Did you redirect the user to PayPal payment page after building the Pay object and made the payment?

If not, add the `redirect_to` line below to your code:

```
....
@response = @api.pay(@pay)
redirect_to api.payment_url(@response)
```

Comment: I received the transaction ID, but money is not transferred to client, and also its not displayed in transaction history

Comment: Well, I also don't see the transactions in the Developer dashboard (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/). I use Delayed chained payment so I check it in the primary receiver PayPal account. Do you have an access to the facilitator PayPal account? If needed, you can change the password here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts

Comment: Ya, but receiver also not receiving the amount

Comment: Could you please pass the payment's payKey to the `get_payment_details` method described above and print the response or at least the value of the paymentExecStatus attribute?

Comment: I have added the payment response

Comment: thanks, and you sure there was a payment made for this PayKey?

Comment: Yes, Payment is created, but client is not receiving the payment. Is there any other steps pending or ?

Comment: Thanks, for the update
I need to pay to emails from server side (API),  there should not any web view. Is there any other way to pay for the particular Email without redirecting to Webpage.

Comment: I think it deserves opening a different question here on SO